# how to map keys as a broadcasted column in dataframe of lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

i have  a dictionary whose keys are `dict_keys(['castor', 'chana', 'coc', 'guargum', 'guarseed', 'jeera', 'rmseed', 'soybean', 'refsoy', 'turmeric', 'dhaniya'])` with respective `values(date,open,high,low,close)` as a list ,how to broadcast this keys as a column to this values.

required output

```
DATE  OPEN  HIGH  LOW  CLOSE  TICKER
XXXX   XXXX XXXX  XXX  XXXX    CASTOR
XXXX   XXXX XXXX  XXX   XXX    CASTOR
```

LIKEWISE FOR EVERY VALUES IN THE LIST WITH THE CORRESPONDING KEYS

Answer (score 0):

If you transform your dictionary to a dataframe you can use the `update` function likeso:

```
data = {
    'castor':  ["1/1/2020", 1, 10, 22, 10], 
    'chana':   ["1/2/2020", 2, 11, 24, 10],
    'coc':     ["1/3/2020", 3, 12, 26, 10],
    'guargum': ["1/4/2020", 4, 13, 28, 10]
}

small_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient="index", columns=["date", "open", "high", "low", "close"])

print(small_df)
             date  open  high  low  close
castor   1/1/2020     1    10   22     10
chana    1/2/2020     2    11   24     10
coc      1/3/2020     3    12   26     10
guargum  1/4/2020     4    13   28     10
```

Now let's create the dataset we want to broadcast this small frame to:

```
empty_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ticker": ["castor", "chana", "coc", "guargum"] * 2,
    "date": np.nan, 
    "open": np.nan, 
    "high": np.nan, 
    "low": np.nan, 
    "close": np.nan
    })

print(empty_df)
    ticker  date  open  high  low  close
0   castor   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
1    chana   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
2      coc   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
3  guargum   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
4   castor   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
5    chana   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
6      coc   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
7  guargum   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
```

Lastly, for the magic. The trick will be to ensure that the index of `empty_df` matches that of the `small_df`, so we'll use `set_index` first. Then we can use the `update` function. The columns will also need to match that of the small_df, but that's already taken care of.

```
final_df = empty_df.set_index("ticker")
final_df.update(small_df) # occurs inplace, so no need to make an output variable

print(final_df)
             date  open  high   low  close
ticker                                    
castor   1/1/2020   1.0  10.0  22.0   10.0
chana    1/2/2020   2.0  11.0  24.0   10.0
coc      1/3/2020   3.0  12.0  26.0   10.0
guargum  1/4/2020   4.0  13.0  28.0   10.0
castor   1/1/2020   1.0  10.0  22.0   10.0
chana    1/2/2020   2.0  11.0  24.0   10.0
coc      1/3/2020   3.0  12.0  26.0   10.0
guargum  1/4/2020   4.0  13.0  28.0   10.0
```